# sha1 + salt encryption fails in php

Tags: php, encryption, sha1, salt

I am trying to secure a password with sha1 hashing to a saltMe() function but the ectrypted password ends up the same no matter what I type in the password field. 
This might lead to a security vulnerability I think.

This is my salt function

```
**************************************************
* sha1 salt string to make a more secure hash 
***************************************************/
function SaltMe() {
   //Secret keyword encrypted with sha1
   return "4cefe49883b6dd1a00565e2a80fb035f348da3aa";
}
```

and this is my login check

```
$select_user_sql = $this->db->selectSQL("*", "tdic_users", "email = '". $email ."' AND password = '". sha1($this->main->SaltMe($password)) ."'");
```

No matter what I type in the password field I end up with:

```
1c2c2961d35148e8dfc83c7b31cf144f0987de9d
```

Which is also what my encrypted password is. But it is not good that I can type whatever I want to match the password.

The login form's actions is validatelogin.php which contain:

```
$user = new UserHandling();
$user->UserLogMeIn($_POST["login_email"], $_POST["login_password"]);
```

And the login function:

```
 /**********************************************************
     * User login function
     * 
     * @param string    | User's email
     * @param string    | User's password
     **********************************************************/
    function UserLogMeIn($email, $password) {

        $select_user_sql = $this->db->selectSQL("*", "tdic_users", "email = '". $email ."' AND password = '". sha1($this->main->SaltMe($password)) ."'");
        $select_user_result = $this->db->SQLquery($select_user_sql);

        if(mysql_num_rows($select_user_result) < 1) {
            $this->main->txtOutput("Wrong email or password", "TXT_ERR"); //The user typed something wrong.
        } else { 
            while($row = $this->db->SQLfetch($select_user_result)) {
                /*** We will check if user have activated the profile ***/
                if($row["activated"] == 0) {
                    $this->main->txtOutput("Your profile haven't been activated! You need to click on the activation link in the email you recieved upon registration.", "TXT_ERR"); //The user haven't activated the new profile. This is necessary for security / spamming reasons
                    $this->main->JSredirector("http://localhost/test/login.php", 5); //Redirect the user back from where he/she came from
                } else {
                    /*** Everything is in order and we will let the user in ***/

                    $_SESSION["usr_logged_in"] = 1;
                    $_SESSION["user_email"] = $row["email"];
                    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row["user_id"];
                    $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row["name"];

                    /*** This will just update the last login field in the user table ***/
                    $fields = array("user_last_logged_in" => time());
                    $update_user_sql = $this->db->updateSQL('tdic_users',  'email = "'. $email .'"', $fields);
                    $this->db->SQLquery($update_user_sql);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can not figure out where the string is set so it always matches!

Comment: You must use a different salt for each password.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: SHA-1 is not encryption, it's hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U return a constant string when salting pass. Try

```
function SaltMe($pass) {
   // Pass salted with Secret keyword encrypted with sha1 
   return "4cefe49883b6dd1a00565e2a80fb035f348da3aa" . $pass;
}
```

Also as SLaks said, u have SQLinj. And it is better to use PDO or mysqli database functions.

Answer (score 4):

Your `SaltMe` function doesn't get an argument, it just always returns the same string. So

```
SaltMe($password)
```

will not do what you intended.

In all seriousness, though: **Stop trying to implement your own password hashing scheme. The very fact that you're here to ask about a mistake in your implementation should be proof enough that you don't understand enough to do so. Use a library, e.g. bcrypt (the [Portable PHP Password Hashing Framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) has an implementation) and [stay far away from ever implementing any crypto code yourself](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/51528/14100).**

Answer (score 1):

You are only hashing the salt string, you haven't prefixed it to your password.

```
"4cefe49883b6dd1a00565e2a80fb035f348da3aa" -> [SHA-1] -> "1c2c2961d35148e8dfc83c7b31cf144f0987de9d"
```

You need to prefix your password with the salt before hashing it.